# Ubuntu 23.04 wifi, shuting down bugs

Tags: 23.04

Since I installed Ubuntu 23.04 on my laptop I have encountered 2 annoying bugs,

1. The first is wifi, although I put the password and saved the network it often notifies me that authentication is required to access,
2. the second bug does not happen often but after hours of playing with steam or lutris, when I go to turn off the pc the screen turns off but the pc stays on and I have to turn it off with the power button...

The specifications: asus with i7 6700hq, 12 gb ram , gtx 950m, realtek wifi, custom kernel liquorix 6.3.3, ubuntu is installed in an external ssd in dualboot with windows 11

Comment: Does it work correctly if you use the Ubuntu 6.2 kernel?

Comment: It isn't a bug. Authentication is always required when logging onto a password-protected wi-fi network.

Comment: because of the wifi it does it also with the generic kernel, although I have saved the password on the first connection it always asks me for it, because of the shutdown it does it every now and then but I have to check with its kernel... I use liquorix to play, I think it was stable

Comment: because of the wifi although I have saved the password on the first connection it always asks me for it

Comment: You have actually asked two questions in one. Please [edit] your question to focus on one of them and ask a separate question for the other. Thanks!